# Iterate over a list of filters

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, filter

I would like to iterate over a a list of combinations of filters that are applied to the multiple columns of a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(    
    ID1 = c("Asset1", "Asset2", "Asset1", "Asset2", "Asset1", "Asset2", "Asset1", "Asset2"),
    ID2 = c("Asset1", "Asset1", "Asset2", "Asset2", "Asset1", "Asset1", "Asset2", "Asset2"),
    var1= c(0.011,      0.012,   0.012,    0.022,   .0011,      0.0012,   0.0012,    0.0022)
)
```

An example:

I would like to compute the value of var1 for the following combinations:

```
filter1: ID1=='Asset1' and ID2=='Asset1'
```

and

```
filter2: ID1=='Asset1' and ID2=='Asset2'
```

For just one combination I could obviosly do this with a dplyr filter like so:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(ID1=='Asset1', ID2=='Asset1')
```

But I would like to do this with a for loop that iterates over all filters:

```
filter_list <- c(filter1, filter2)

for (filter_i in filter_list){
    df %>% filter(filter_i)
}
```

Comment: Are the filter[n]s always just exactly equal to values, or could they be more complex - `ID1 != 'Asset1'` for instance? If they're always simple, you could reconceptualise this as a join and summarise, e.g.: `filts <- data.frame(num=1:2, ID1 = c("Asset1","Asset1"), ID2 = c("Asset1","Asset2")); df %>% inner_join(filts) %>% summarise(var1sum = sum(var1), .by="num")`

Comment: why not just `split` ie and then select the ones you want? ie `a <- split(df,~ID1+ID2)` then do `a[c('Asset1.Asset1', 'Asset1.Asset2')]`

Comment: the filters can be more complex in the sense that 3 columns are involved which are binary.

Comment: The split would still not allow me to do this for more combinations .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a filter list from `unique` assets living in columns `1:2`. Next, generate `filter_list` using all 2-permutations using `expand.grid`.

```
> assets <- unique(unlist(df[1:2]))
> filter_list <- expand.grid(assets, assets) |> asplit(1)
```

Finally you can `lapply` with `subset` over the list.

```
> lapply(filter_list, \(x) subset(x=df, ID1 == x[1] & ID2 == x[2]))
[[1]]
     ID1    ID2   var1
1 Asset1 Asset1 0.0110
5 Asset1 Asset1 0.0011

[[2]]
     ID1    ID2   var1
2 Asset2 Asset1 0.0120
6 Asset2 Asset1 0.0012

[[3]]
     ID1    ID2   var1
3 Asset1 Asset2 0.0120
7 Asset1 Asset2 0.0012

[[4]]
     ID1    ID2   var1
4 Asset2 Asset2 0.0220
8 Asset2 Asset2 0.0022
```

Or, if you insist on a `for` loop

```
> res <- vector('list', length(filter_list))  ## initialize
> for (i in seq_along(filter_list)) {
+   res[[i]] <- subset(x=df, ID1 == filter_list[[i]][1] & ID2 == filter_list[[i]][2])
+ }
> res
[[1]]
     ID1    ID2   var1
1 Asset1 Asset1 0.0110
5 Asset1 Asset1 0.0011

[[2]]
     ID1    ID2   var1
2 Asset2 Asset1 0.0120
6 Asset2 Asset1 0.0012

[[3]]
     ID1    ID2   var1
3 Asset1 Asset2 0.0120
7 Asset1 Asset2 0.0012

[[4]]
     ID1    ID2   var1
4 Asset2 Asset2 0.0220
8 Asset2 Asset2 0.0022
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID1 = c("Asset1", "Asset2", "Asset1", "Asset2", 
"Asset1", "Asset2", "Asset1", "Asset2"), ID2 = c("Asset1", "Asset1", 
"Asset2", "Asset2", "Asset1", "Asset1", "Asset2", "Asset2"), 
    var1 = c(0.011, 0.012, 0.012, 0.022, 0.0011, 0.0012, 0.0012, 
    0.0022)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: This looks great, thank you. My apologhies, I am realizing now that my min Example dataframe is too different from my original data and I wasn't able to transfer your solution, so I had to repost it here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77662910/iterate-over-a-list-of-filters-and-all-possible-combinations

Answer (score 3):

Using `quos` and bang-bang-bang aka  `!!!` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

filters <- list(
  filter1 = quos(ID1 == "Asset1", ID2 == "Asset1"),
  filter2 = quos(ID1 == "Asset1", ID2 == "Asset2")
)

lapply(filters, \(x) {
  df %>%
    filter(!!!x)
})
#> $filter1
#>      ID1    ID2   var1
#> 1 Asset1 Asset1 0.0110
#> 2 Asset1 Asset1 0.0011
#> 
#> $filter2
#>      ID1    ID2   var1
#> 1 Asset1 Asset2 0.0120
#> 2 Asset1 Asset2 0.0012
```

Comment: Thank you Stefan. Could I do this with a for loop as well?

Comment: Sure. `lapply` or `purrr::map` is a bit more elegant and it will return a named list of data.frames. But you could also go on with a for loop.

Comment: Understood, but how would I do this with a for loop? Would I just do this: for (i in filters){df %>% filter(!!!i) ?