# Iterate over a list of filters and all possible combinations

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I would like to iterate over all possible list of combinations of filters that are applied to the multiple columns of a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(    
    Indicator1 = c(0,1,1),
    Indicator2 = c(1,1,0),
    Indicator3 = c(1,0,1),
    var1= c(0.011,      0.012,   0.012)
)
```

For just one combination I could obviosly do this with a dplyr filter like so:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(Indicator1 ==1, Indicator2==1, Indicator3==1)
```

But I would like to do this with a for loop that iterates over all combinations

Answer (score 2):

Use `split`:

```
 split(df, ~Indicator1+Indicator2+Indicator3)
$`0.0.0`
[1] Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3 var1      
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$`1.0.0`
[1] Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3 var1      
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$`0.1.0`
[1] Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3 var1      
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$`1.1.0`
  Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3  var1
2          1          1          0 0.012

$`0.0.1`
[1] Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3 var1      
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$`1.0.1`
  Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3  var1
3          1          0          1 0.012

$`0.1.1`
  Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3  var1
1          0          1          1 0.011

$`1.1.1`
[1] Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3 var1      
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

---

If you need data that only exits in the `df`:

```
Filter(nrow, split(df, ~Indicator1+Indicator2+Indicator3))

$`1.1.0`
  Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3  var1
2          1          1          0 0.012

$`1.0.1`
  Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3  var1
3          1          0          1 0.012

$`0.1.1`
  Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3  var1
1          0          1          1 0.011
```

---

Other codes include:

```
split(df, df[-4])
split(df, interaction(df[-4]))
split(df, do.call(paste,df[-4]))
```

Comment: Neat! (+1) Can you please explain why `df0 = data.frame(); df1 = data.frame(a = 1L); Filter(nrow, list(df0, df1))` evaluates to `FALSE` for an empty data frame? Why is an explicit condition, i.e., `nrow(.) > 0L`  not required?

Comment: @Friede an integer 0 is implicitly coerced to logical. ie `if(nrow(..))` is the same as `if(nrow(..)>0)` due to implicit coercion

Answer (score 1):

This is just slightly more complicated than your [previous example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77657848/6574038) as you have to include one more column.

```
> assets <- unique(unlist(df[1:3]))
> filter_list <- expand.grid(assets, assets, assets) |> asplit(1) 
> lapply(filter_list, \(x) subset(x=df, Indicator1 == x[1] & Indicator2 == x[2] & Indicator3 == x[3]))
[[1]]
[1] Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3 var1      
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

[[2]]
[1] Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3 var1      
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

[[3]]
[1] Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3 var1      
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

[[4]]
  Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3  var1
2          1          1          0 0.012

[[5]]
[1] Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3 var1      
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

[[6]]
  Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3  var1
3          1          0          1 0.012

[[7]]
  Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3  var1
1          0          1          1 0.011

[[8]]
[1] Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3 var1      
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

If you don't like the 0-row data frames (case they also appear from your original data), you can do

```
> lapply(filter_list, \(x) subset(x=df, Indicator1 == x[1] & Indicator2 == x[2] & Indicator3 == x[3])) |>
+   {\(.) .[sapply(., \(x) nrow(x) > 0)]}()
[[1]]
  Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3  var1
2          1          1          0 0.012

[[2]]
  Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3  var1
3          1          0          1 0.012

[[3]]
  Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3  var1
1          0          1          1 0.011
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned a "*for loop that iterates over all combinations*" here is an explicit approach:

```r
cn = unique(unlist(df[-4L]))

for(i in cn) {
  for(j in cn) {
    for(k in cn) {
      print(df[df$Indicator1 == i & df$Indicator2 == j & df$Indicator3 == k, ])
    }
  }
}
#> [1] Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3 var1      
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
#> [1] Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3 var1      
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
#> [1] Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3 var1      
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
#>   Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3  var1
#> 1          0          1          1 0.011
#> [1] Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3 var1      
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
#>   Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3  var1
#> 3          1          0          1 0.012
#>   Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3  var1
#> 2          1          1          0 0.012
#> [1] Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3 var1      
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

without zero-sized row results

```
for(i in cn) {
  for(j in cn) {
    for(k in cn) {
      df[df$Indicator1 == i & df$Indicator2 == j & df$Indicator3 == k, ] |>
        { \(.) if(nrow(.) > 0L) print(.) }()
    }
  }
}
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data**

```r
df <- data.frame(    
  Indicator1 = c(0,1,1),
  Indicator2 = c(1,1,0),
  Indicator3 = c(1,0,1),
  var1= c(0.011,      0.012,   0.012)
)
df
#>   Indicator1 Indicator2 Indicator3  var1
#> 1          0          1          1 0.011
#> 2          1          1          0 0.012
#> 3          1          0          1 0.012
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more general start-to-finish approach using the tidyverse (since you are already using dplyr). Instead of starting with the derived indicators, you may also start with the explicit filter definitions and build the list of corresponding filtered data sets.

```r
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(rlang)

data    <- mtcars %>% as_tibble()
# define filters as character vector
filters <- c('mpg > 30', 'am == 1', 'am == 0 & carb > 3') %>%
  set_names(., paste0('filter', 1:length(.)))
# build vector of all possible combinations of filters (apart from no filters)
possible_filters <- map(1:length(filters),
    ~combn(filters, .x) %>% as.data.frame() %>% as_tibble() %>% unite(filter_comb, everything(), sep = ' & ') %>% pull(filter_comb)) %>%  
  unlist() %>% 
  set_names()

# apply each combination to data set of interest
filtered_list <- imap(
  possible_filters, 
  ~filter(mtcars, !!! parse_exprs(.x) ) %>% mutate(filter_applied = .y) 
) 


# note that still works for 0-row result tibble
filtered_list[1:2]
#> $`mpg > 30 & am == 1 & am == 0 & carb > 3`
#>  [1] mpg            cyl            disp           hp             drat          
#>  [6] wt             qsec           vs             am             gear          
#> [11] carb           filter_applied
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
#> 
#> $`mpg > 30 & mpg > 30 & am == 1`
#>                 mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Fiat 128       32.4   4 78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#> Honda Civic    30.4   4 75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#> Toyota Corolla 33.9   4 71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> Lotus Europa   30.4   4 95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#>                               filter_applied
#> Fiat 128       mpg > 30 & mpg > 30 & am == 1
#> Honda Civic    mpg > 30 & mpg > 30 & am == 1
#> Toyota Corolla mpg > 30 & mpg > 30 & am == 1
#> Lotus Europa   mpg > 30 & mpg > 30 & am == 1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>